# What font is used in this CAREERS 2.0 advertisement?

Tags: discussion, jobs, fonts

I would like to know what font is being used for html code in the careers 2.0 advertisement located on the side of the site.

[image: Careers 2.0]

Comment: Which font? There is more than one...

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: @animuson: The one in the center.  The one at the bottom is unremarkable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree. The one at the bottom is remarkably clean, stylistic and eye-catching. =D

Comment: @J.Steen Lol, well, I meant the one in the middle. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### OCR A

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/ocr-a/ocr-a/

[image]

See [here](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=9&ch%5B1%5D=8&ch%5B2%5D=7&ch%5B3%5D=6&ch%5B4%5D=5&ch%5B5%5D=3&ch%5B6%5D=2&ch%5B7%5D=1&ch%5B8%5D=4&wtfserver=aws_wtf2&id=000099745177706d0006cac700007c06&glyphcount=9&imageid=0&x=82&y=40) for analysis.

Comment: Tell me you didn't know that off the top of your head.

Comment: Nope.  See the bottom link in my answer.  I uploaded a clip of the numbers only into WhatTheFont.  It took a couple of tries to get it right.

Comment: *"Your search session has expired. Please start again."*

Comment: Aw, bummer.  They don't keep things forever like the rest of the Internet.  Oh, well.  There was that font, and about 20 others that weren't exact matches.

Comment: super awesome! :)